# Can we add custom fields in Search Panel Fields of Provider Search Component of Health Cloud?

Tags: health-cloud

I want to add one custom field in search panel of Provider Search component which is a standard component. Is this possible ?
Currently only some standard fields are available there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by creating custom field on Healthcare Provider object and on
Care Provider Searchable Field.
Once fields are created navigate to Care Provider Search Config from Setup and create new Care Provider Search Config.

[image]

Here mapped object will be Healthcare Provider and source field will API name of field created on Healthcare Provider object and target field will be API name of field created on Care Provider Searchable Field object.

Once this is done custom field will be available in Provider Search component panel.